# Implementation of map on binary tree using fold

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, fold

I'm struggling with define map over tree using `foldBT`. My idea is to convert the tree into list, map the operator over the list, and then convert the list back to tree. But it sounds inefficient and also doesn't make use of `foldBT`... I tried to run `foldBT (*2) Nil (numTree [3,5,7]` but ghci reported error. I don't really understand how the function `foldBt` works. An example would be great.

```
data SimpleBT a = Nil | N a (SimpleBT a) (SimpleBT a) deriving (Show, Eq)

foldBT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> SimpleBT a -> b
foldBT f e Nil = e
foldBT f e (N a left right) = f a (foldBT f e left) (foldBT f e right)

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> SimpleBT a -> SimpleBT b
mapTree f Nil = Nil
mapTree f (N a left right) = N (f a) (mapTree f left) (mapTree f right)

size :: SimpleBT a -> Int
size Nil = 0
size (N _ left right) = 1 + size left + size right

insert ::  SimpleBT a -> a -> SimpleBT a
insert Nil a = N a Nil Nil
insert (N x left right) a
  | size left <= size right = N x (insert left a) right
  | otherwise = N x left (insert right a)

numTree :: [a] -> SimpleBT a
numTree xs = foldl insert Nil xs
```

Comment: Hint: how would you make a `foldBT` that leaves the tree intact?

Answer (score 5):

Let us hypothesize `mapTree f = foldBT g e`, and solve for `g` and `e`. The definition of `foldBT` says:

```
foldBT g e Nil = e
```

Meanwhile, from the definition of `mapTree`, we get:

```
mapTree f Nil = Nil
```

From our hypothesis that `mapTree f = foldBT g e`, we can transform the second equation and stick it next to the first equation:

```
foldBT g e Nil = Nil
foldBT g e Nil = e
```

So `e = Nil`.

Let's do the other clauses now. The definition of `foldBT` says:

```
foldBT g e (N a left right) = g a (foldBT g e left) (foldBT g e right)
```

Meanwhile, `mapTree`'s definition says:

```
mapTree f (N a left right) = N (f a) (mapTree f left) (mapTree f right)
```

Again, using our hypothesis `mapTree f = foldBT g e`, we can now rewrite this equation, and stick it next to the first one:

```
foldBT g e (N a left right) = N (f a) (foldBT g e left) (foldBT g e right)
foldBT g e (N a left right) = g a (foldBT g e left) (foldBT g e right)
```

So `g a = N (f a)` would validate this equation. Writing these all down in one spot, we get:

```
mapTree f = foldBT g e where
    e = Nil
    g a = N (f a)
```

You can inline the definitions of `e` and `g` if you like; I would.

```
mapTree f = foldBT (N . f) Nil
```

Comment: I really like your solution. How do you come to the idea of `g /= f`

Comment: @Jung Your mind should go the other way: why assume `g = f` to begin with? Never assume an equality until you're forced to! A better question would be, "How did I come to the idea that there might be an equality relating `mapTree` and `foldBT`?", and for that, I cheated: you yourself demanded it in the original question text.

Comment: good tip! I do indeed know they are related through the equation `mapTree f = foldBT _ e` I struggled because I assume `g = f` But it makes sense that couldnt happen since that would lead to `f a = N (f a)` Once again thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the `foldBT` function is that it takes an argument for each constructor of your data type (plus the one holding the whole `SimpleBT a` itself that you wish to fold over). The first one, of type `a -> b -> b -> b` corresponds to the recursive `N` constructor, and shows how to combine the value at the node with the results of the fold of the two subtrees into the result of the entire fold. The second argument corresponds to the `Nil` constructor, and since this constructor takes no arguments, the corresponding argument to `fold` is simply a constant.

It's completely analagous to folding over a list. The list type `[a]` also has 2 constructors. One of them takes an `a` and a list and adds the element to the front of the list: `a -> [a] -> [a]`, this gives rise to a "fold function" of type `a -> b -> b`. The other constructor, as in your case, is nullary (the empty list), so again corresponds to an argument whose type is just `b`. Hence `foldr` for a list has type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`.

There is a great discussion of this, with more examples, in this chapter of the Haskell wikibook: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Other_data_structures

As for how to build a map from a fold, for your particular tree type - bearing in mind what I've said above, you need (given a mapping function `f :: a -> a0`), we need to think about what this does to both the `Nil` tree, and what it does recursively to trees with a leaf and 2 branches. Also, since our return type will of course be another tree of the same type, `b` here will be `SimpleBT a0`.

For `Nil`, obviously we want `map` to leave it unchanged, so the second argument to `foldBT` will be `Nil`. And for the other constructor, we want the `map` to apply the base function to the value at the leaf, and then recursively map over the 2 branches. This leads us to the function `\a left right -> N (f a) (mapTree f left) (mapTree f right)`.

So we can conclude that the map function can be defined as follows (thanks to @DanielWagner and @WillemVanOnsen for helping me fix my first broken version):

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> SimpleBT a -> SimpleBT b
mapTree f = foldBT foldFunc Nil
    where foldFunc a l r = N (f a) l r
```

Comment: In a fold function, the `l` and `r` are typically "already folded", so you can simplify the last one to `foldFunc a l r = N (f a) l r`. You also thus forgo the `N` constructor :).

Comment: Yeah, thanks - I'd just figured both of those out myself. Will edit now :)

Comment: thanks for the reference ! One question: What does the last `b` in the type signature of `foldBT` represent ? Does it have the type of `Nil` which is polymorphic?

Comment: The last `b` is the type of the return value. It's arbitrary, but it determines the types of the arguments, in the way I described: you need a `b` for the `Nil` tree, and the function which deals with the `N` constructor must have type `a -> b -> b -> b` as it takes the leaf value and the results of folding the subtrees and computes the new result. Again, it's exactly analogous to folding a list, where the type signature is `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [ a] -> b`.